# rsync does not recognize windows path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rsync, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to build a docker container in windows 7 (Docker tool box with oracle VM) by running a shell script in git bash, and the script has the command with rsync like shown below:

```
rsync -a --exclude='*/node_modules' $PROJECT_PATH/project_name/src/ ./project_name/src
```

and the value for `$PROJECT_PATH=/c/Users/yajnesh_rai/git`

This is what I see in console:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

Some online documentation says to use forward slashes for path without drive name, and I tried this way

```
$PROJECT_PATH=\\Users\\yajnesh_rai\\git
```

This makes rsync work, but fails to copy file, like shown below:

```
\Users\yajnesh_rai\git/project_name/src/folder_name/file_name: warning: directory does not exist.
```

I installed rsync on windows by following steps mentioned in this post: https://blog.tiger-workshop.com/add-rsync-to-git-bash-for-windows/

Any help to tackle the issue is appreciated!! Thanks in advance

Comment: found a solution?

Answer (score 6):

#### Rsync has a problem with absolute paths in Windows

I had the exact same problem when using `rsync` on Windows (Windows 10 64-bit).
`rsync` doesn't like absolute Windows paths because of the `C:` in the path. Therefore, you should:

> Replace `C:` with `/cygdrive/c`.

#### Usage example

This is how I use `rsync` on Windows:

```sh
rsync -av --delete /cygdrive/c/Users/Kristof/src_folder/ /cygdrive/c/Users/Kristof/dst_folder/
```

Rsync synchronizes source folder `C:/Users/Kristof/src_folder/` to target folder `C:/Users/Kristof/dst_folder/`

I use the following flags:

- `-a`, `--archive`               archive mode; equals `-rlptgoD` (no `-H`,`-A`,`-X`)

  - `-r`, `--recursive`               recurse into directories
  - `-l`, `--links`                   copy symlinks as symlinks
  - `-p`, `--perms`                   preserve permissions
  - `-t`, `--times`                   preserve modification times
  - `-g`, `--group`                   preserve group
  - `-o`, `--owner`                   preserve owner (super-user only)
  - `-D`                              same as `--devices` `--specials`

    - `--devices`                         preserve device files (super-user only)
    - `--specials`                        preserve special files
- `-v`, `--verbose`               increase verbosity
- `--delete`                delete extraneous files from dest dirs